# In MediaWiki: Check if user account is blocked within page

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

In MediaWiki I'd like to create a page that links to a user account. As we use blocking in order to deactivate user accounts (as there is no other way provided to achieve this) it would be nice to present a note next to a link if the account has been blocked. Therefor I require some way to distinguish between different states of a user account.

Therefor my question: Is there a parser function or some other kind of instrument to detect if a user account is blocked? I can't find one. Or is there some other way how to achieve this functionality within a page?

Note: Deleting a user page is not an option. There is an `{{#ifexist}}` parser function which could check for existence of a page but I do not want to delete the user pages and do not want to confuse admins. The "user-is-blocked" flag is the only thing available that we could perform some kind of branching on. Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could install the [markblocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-markblocked.js) gadget from English Wikipedia. This would do it client-side and not as part of the page parse, which is sort of preferable as it reacts better to changes in blockedness of a user (and will work on any link to the user, regardless of how it's added to the wiki).

There is currently talk about the possibility of turning this gadget into an extension; see [T180555](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T180555) for more about that (it'd make it easier to install).

Also, the extension might work for displaying indicators about membership of different groups (this is what the [markadmins](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-markAdmins.js) gadget does), so for example you could change your workflow to, rather than blocking old users, adding them to a 'noncurrent' user group (and giving that group no rights). Then, you could vary the display of the usernames according to user group.

Comment: That's an interesting approach: Let the Wiki framework render the page and perform an additional API call to modify the rendered page. Not verey beautiful from a software development perspective but probably the easiest way to get MediaWiki what I'd like it to do. Thank you, I've to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra class to the username link in the [HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/HtmlPageLinkRendererEnd) hook. See [this patch](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/370137/) for something similar (except that it adds the class for links outside the page content).

Comment: Hm. So you suggest that I patch the Wiki code? That actually makes sense: It might not be the easiest approach but maybe the best way of how to accomplish what I'm looking for. I've to think about it. But: Does "Linker.php" mean this file is dealing with references = links within a Wiki page????

Comment: Adding a hook handler is not really a patch (you don't need to change upstream code and hook signatures are more stable than most things you'd have to rely on in a patch). Linker used to deal with all link generation; we are in the middle of a slow-moving refactoring now so some of it is in LinkRenderer. You don't really need to care about that though, that's the point of a hook system - it decouples the code that interferes from the code that's being interfered with. The patch is only relevant in that it shows you what kind of tools you need to use to get the information.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that information. I was just wondering that s.o. chose "Linker" as an identifier for that system component. Glad to here you restructure that to "LinkRenderer" in the future. I've to recover from a complete system crash of my develop machine first until I can continue on that topic. Maybe I'll take exactly this hook approach: I've already some experience writing MW plugins. Nevertheless I require to perform the rendering on client side: I really need to add some text like "disabled". Ideally I'd like have some filtering: I guess SMW is no help in this case. We'll see.